# Treasure Planet in Space about a young man with a natural resistance to a particular disease

Tags: story-identification

There is this science fiction novel much similar or having a name similar to treasure planet. The things i can remember about the book are

1. There were whale like creatures which were eventually discovered to be space-ships
2. The main character was discovered to have a natural resistance to a particular deadly disease that was ravaging the known world
3. There were pirates in the story line.
4. There were alien creatures - some reptilian creature tagging along with the main character and the pirate crew.

Comment: There's a very extensive list of "space whale" stories here; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceWhale